# php multidimensional array check if value is greater

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

I have below array

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 46
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 0
        )

)
```

and I want to search in this array if any of value is greater than 0. How can I do this?

Comment: This isn't difficult to do. Surely you tried something, right?

Comment: A combination of [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (or any other means of iterating over an array) should do the job nicely. Try using them yourself and post an update/question if you get stuck, but do try something first.

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your array elements, I've assigned it to a variable called $arrayElements in this example...

```
$qtyValue = 0;    
foreach($arrayElements as $arrayElement) {
   $qtyValue = ($arrayElement['qty'] > 0) ? true : false; 
   if($qtyValue) {
      break;
   }
}

if($qtyValue) {
  //Value greater than 0 exists
}
```

Hope that makes sense... if not, look up [Foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loops

Other PHP functions can help walk through this as Andrew states in the comments, but start with for / foreach loops so you understand the logic behind it.

Refactored a bit:

```
$qtyValue = 0;    
foreach($arrayElements as $arrayElement) {
   if($arrayElement['qty'] > 0) {
      $qtyValue = true
      break;
   }
}

if($qtyValue) {
  //Value greater than 0 exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you**

**First method** : *use `array_map` and `array_filter` function to get the desired result :*

```
$arr =Array ('0' => Array('qty'=>46),'1'=>Array('qty'=>1),'2'=>Array('qty'=>0));

$quantities = array_filter(array_column($arr, 'qty'),function($n){
    return ($n > 0) ;
});

print_r($quantities);
/* $quantities contains all qty higher than 0 */
```

working demo : https://eval.in/1016144

**Second**  *way using `foreach`*

```
$arr =Array ('0' => Array('qty'=>46),'1'=>Array('qty'=>1),'2'=>Array('qty'=>0));
foreach ($arr as $key => $item) 
 {
    if ($item['qty'] > 0 )
    {
        $data[] = $item['qty'];
    }
 }
 print_r($data);
 /* $data contains all qty higher than 0 */
```

working demo : https://eval.in/1016097

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 46
    [1] => 1
)
```

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_column and max.

```
Echo max(array_column($arr, "qty"));
```

Or if you want a bool return

```
If(max(array_column($arr, "qty")){
    Echo "yes";
}Else{
    Echo "no";
}
```

Max will take the maximum value from the array items qty.
And if the value is more than 0 the if will be true.